# how create not anonymous function for map in Object on JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Hi all I want refractor my code.
I have this sample object:

```
class Obj {
    constructor(){
      this.data = [
        {'name':'Tom','age':23},
        {'name':'John','age':30},
        {'name':'Filip','age':32},
    ];
        this.init();
  }
    init() {
        this.newData = this.data.map(function addYear(person) {
            person.age= person.age + 1;
            return person;
          });
       }
 }
```

How can i put this addYear function and declare her in object, when i try 
something like this it wasn't work:

```
class Obj {
  //...... old code....
 addYear(person){
    person.age= person.age + 1;
    return person;
 }
 init() {
    this.newData = this.data.map(this.addYear(person)); // this doesn't work 
 }
}
```

is there some way how achive this? thanx

Comment: You have no need to use `.map()` in the first place. You're both mutating the original objects, and then replacing them with a new Array of the same objects. Might as well just use `.forEach()`, and remove the `return person;` and the `this.newData =`.

Comment: And a method of the class usually would operate on some member of the class, like how `init()` operates on `this.data`. If this is to be a utility for the `person` objects, maybe it should be a static method. Or maybe you should have a `Person` class that has an `addYear` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to call **.map** object as `object => object` ! Make sure you have return data in each function.

```
class Obj {
    constructor(){
      this.data = [
        {'name':'Tom','age':23},
        {'name':'John','age':30},
        {'name':'Filip','age':32},
    ];
        return this.init();
  }
 init() {
        this.newData = this.data.map(person => this.addYear(person));
        return this.newData;
}

 addYear(person){
    person.age= person.age + 1;
    return person;
 }
 }
 console.log(new Obj());
 //result     
 0: Object
         age:24
         name:"Tom"
 1: Object
         age:31
         name:"John"
 2: Object
         age:33
         name:"Filip"
```

Comment: Thanks. Why are you put return statment in  constructor?

Comment: If you don't put return, you will get old object and update object ! Just depend on you